# How do I exclude products with discount from coupon codes?

Tags: product, price, special-price

I need put a coupon code. But I don't need the products with any discount **(catalog price rule)**. I want to make discount coupon only for products with normal price.

Is this even possible?

Comment: It is not possible without a customization to the cart rule validation

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved this problem:

1. Create a new product attribute (e.g. 'catalog_rule_active' type Yes/No) and attach to your attribute set. Make sure you set "Use For Promo Rule Conditions" to Yes in storefront properties.
2. Create a cron job that runs shortly after the default catalogrule_apply_all cronjob (default run time is 1am) or schedule to your requirements.

- the apply all cronjob updates the catalogrule_product table in your db. This table stores all the product_ids that Catalog Rules are applied to.
- your cron job needs to collect the product ids from this table
- then your cron should retrieve a product collection of all items that have the catalog_rule_active attribute set to Yes
- then you can use the active product ids to update the attribute to Yes
- and then you can filter out the expiring product ids, and update the attribute to No

see example - customise logic as required

> ```
>     public function execute()
>     {
>      try {
>           $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
>           $tableName = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('catalogrule_product');
>           $date = strtotime($this->dateTime->gmtDate());
>
>           $select = $connection->select()
>               ->from($tableName)
>               ->where('from_time = 0 or from_time < ?', $date)
>               ->where('to_time = 0 or to_time > ?', $date);
>
>           $ruleProducts = $connection->fetchAll($select);
>
>           $productIds = [];
>           foreach ($ruleProducts as $ruleProduct) {
>             $productIds[] = $ruleProduct['product_id'];
>           }
>           $productIds = array_unique($productIds);
>
>           $productCollection = $this->productCollection->create()
>                               ->addAttributeToFilter('catalog_rule_active', 1);
>           $oldProducts = [];
>           foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
>             $oldProducts[] = $product->getId();
>           }
>
>           $productsToRemove = array_diff($oldProducts, $productIds);
>
>           foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
>             $product = $this->productModel->load($productId);
>             $product->setData('catalog_rule_active', 1);
>             $product->save();
>           }
>
>           foreach ($productsToRemove as $removals) {
>             $product = $this->productModel->load($removals);
>             $product->setData('catalog_rule_active', 0);
>             $product->save();
>           }
>     } catch (\Exception $e) {
>         $this->_logger->error($e->getMessage());
>     }
> }
> ```

3. When you set up any Sales Cart Price rule, set your desired conditions (brand, category, etc) and then add a second condition that excludes any product that has this catalog_rule_active attribute set to Yes.
   [image: conditions page]

The added benefit of this is then you can add your new attribute to filters/columns in the admin Product screen so you can easily see any products that are currently captured by a catalog rule :)

Update: I modified the code from this original answer to capture configurable products as well. You can see the fullcode here https://github.com/bernieu2/magento2-catalogruleactive

Comment: is there any full example for this? github code or something?

Comment: here you go, I put the files you'd need to make this here https://github.com/bernieu2/magento2-catalogruleactive

Comment: great, thank you i have install the module.. but it still doesn't update any product Active catalog rule attribute, should i wait for full day so it's could start with cronjob?

Comment: You can alter schedule in crontab.xml to whatever you like. Eg if you want to run it everyday at 4:30pm it would be 30 16 * * * - you can set it for the next minute or so to force it to run, just make sure to clear cache after changing schedule. https://crontab.guru/ is helpful for testing your schedule

Comment: yes i got it.. but the problem i have that this store have more than 4000 products, so it's take too much time to update the Attribute value for each products... any suggestion ideas?

Comment: you're right, I didn't consider store with large number of products.. I found another method of updating attributes that is far quicker. I tested with 6.4k products - old method with repository took 30 mins to update; new method took 6 seconds. I updated the file in github to use the new method.

Comment: thanks, i'll try it and let you know what happens with me.. plz share your contact with me, we need magento 2 developers to work with us.